# Python and SQL Interactions: Query Multiple Tables & Insert Data from GUI

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, user-interface, tkinter

I am working on a make my life easier type of program.

What I am wanting to do is make a GUI so a user (me and a few friends) can enter data to my SQL table. However I am wanting to connect to 2 different databases, compiling into 1.

It consists of 3 different values and I need one of those values (#1) to be from a drop-down box pulled from db1, value #2 entered by user but cannot be greater than a numerical value assigned to value#1  pulled from db1 and finally just my userid.

Example db1 has customer and # of products bought, Value#1 has drop down of all customers that have purchases, (I select customer ABC, they have 4 active purchases), in values#2 I can enter 4 or less (for shipment purposes). Then my userid.

Then I hit submit button and it A)auto inserts into table or B)populates a list and I hit a button and all is inserted into table at once (see image).

I have the rough GUI working and I am entering info into my test.db but I am unsure on the drop-down options or the part where I would connect to a different db to pull the customers w/ active orders info.
(Bonus can the GUI show the values I have entered as a row/column setting and then submit all at once to SQL or do I need to do one at a time?)

Thanks for any help.

```
    import pyodbc 
    import tkinter as tk


    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=server_name;'
                      'Database=db_name;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM db_name.TestDB')


    window = tk.Tk()

    label1 = tk.Label(window, text='Value1')
    label2 = tk.Label(window, text='Value2')
    label3 = tk.Label(window, text='Value3')

    entry1 = tk.Entry(window)
    entry2 = tk.Entry(window)
    entry3 = tk.Entry(window)

    def submittal():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO TestDB.dbo.Info (Value1, Value2, Value3)
                VALUES
                (?, ?, ?),
                (entry1.get(),entry2.get(),entry3.get())
                ''')
    window.destroy()


    button1 = tk.Button(window, text='Submit', command=submittal)


    conn.commit()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making your dropdown you can use `Combobox` widget inside ttk.
(If you don't know what ttk is, it has all the features of tkinter as well as some other cool widgets like progress bars and many more. Refer to ttk python docs here:[Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html))

Then you could link your `entry2` to a textvariable so that it goes to some function which checks whether the number inside it is greater than purchases or not.

Example:

```
variable = StringVar()
#Then set the value of `textvariable` option in tkinter to variable

entry_name = Entry(root, textvariable=variable)
entry_name.trace("w", name_of_function)
```

Inside the function, you could check conditions after selecting it using `SELECT`.

Note: The `trace` method should be in `w` mode. It is essential for making changes.